# RabbitMQ dead letter exchange - route by "x-death.reason" or "x-first-death-reason" header

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I am trying to set up RabbitMQ to route messages through a Dead Letter Exchange based on the death reason (either "x-death.reason" or "x-first-death-reason" would do).

My understanding is that when a message dies that "x-death.reason" and "x-first-death-reason" are set as headers when the messages is sent to the DLX. So my reasoning is that I should be able to set up an exchange with `type=headers` to be able to route by the value of these headers.

Unfortunately, I just can't get it to work.

The DLX is set up like

[image: dead letter queue setup]

However each dead message gets routed to **all** of the bound queues.

[image: target queues]

i.e. the filtering/routing is not working.

Can someone please let me know how to configure this correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html#exchange-headers

> Note that headers beginning with the string x- will not be used to evaluate matches.

Answer (score 1):

From same documentation as @abaelter wrote about [exchange-headers](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html#exchange-headers), but updated:

> For `any` and `all`, headers beginning with the string `x-` will not be
> used to evaluate matches. Setting `x-match` to `any-with-x` or
> `all-with-x` will also use headers beginning with the string `x-` to
> evaluate matches.

Now you can use `x-match` with value `any-with-x` and headers with `x-` shoud start works.

Something like this:

[image: rabbitmq dlx.text exchange setup]